# PHP multiply post value by a number and bind it in query

Tags: php, mysqli

When I run below query, it runs fine:

```
$query->bind_param('ssi', $Email, $name, $_POST['quantity_value']);
```

But when I try to multiply the quantity value by 2 then code does not run:

```
$query->bind_param('ssi', $Email, $name, $_POST['quantity_value'] * 2);
```

And this works fine:

```
$quantity_value = $_POST['quantity_value'] * 2;
$query->bind_param('ssi', $Email, $name, $quantity_value);
```

Edit:

I also got error:

> Cannot pass parameter 3 by reference

Comment: What is in $_POST['quantity_value']?  Are you sure it is a number?  If so try doing echo of $_POST['quantity_value'] * 2 to see the result.

Comment: try to put it inside the parenthesis `$query->bind_param('ssi', $Email, $name, ($_POST['quantity_value'] * 2));`

Comment: It is a input type=text which contains a number.

Comment: Values in $_POST collected from a form are all strings, meaning that multiplication should return 0. This might not be a cause of the problem, but could definitely lead to unexpected results. Additionally, do you get any error messages?

Comment: this works fine:   $quantity_value = $_POST['quantity_value'] * 2;
$query->bind_param('ssi', $Email, $name, $quantity_value);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bind_param` means what it says: it binds parameters. This is useful if, for instance, you want to do a loop:

```
$i = 0;
$query->bind_param("i",$i);
for( $i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    $query->execute();
}
// result: ten rows numbered 0 to 9
```

However, bound values are passed by reference. You cannot reference the result of a calculation or function call, *only* variables can be passed by reference.

This is why `$quantity_value = $_POST['quantity_value'] * 2` allows it to work, because you now have a single variable that you are binding to your query.

Comment: And I thought I am hallucinating!